# Do I need to install all VS workloads in the TFS build server?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build, msbuild

Currently we only have Visual Studio 2015 installed on our TFS build server. I'd like to put VS 2017 and VS 2019 onto the build server.

Does that mean I need to install all possible workloads for both of them, in the build server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice is to simulate the build server to the developer machine, so it's good to install all the workloads that installed on the VS in the developer machine.

If you don't want, you can install only [Visual Studio Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019), it allows you to build VS projects. but sometimes if the developer wrote some specific code in specific workload that build tools not support it, the TFS build will fail.

Comment: Thankfully, the new build tools (2017+) do have a lot of configurable components now and can do a lot of things the old ones couldn't.

Comment: This is good to know. I think my best approach would be to install the Visual Studio Build Tools. Either that or I'm wondering if installing Visual Studio Community Edition would suffice?

Comment: Build Tools for vs is enough for your situation. And for vs community, it can also work if you install necessary workloads.

Comment: Thank you, Lance.