# Two more questions related to the VS Build Tools and VS agents

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild, visual-studio-2019

Earlier I asked if I needed to [install various Visual Studio workloads onto the Build server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56025964/do-i-need-to-install-all-vs-workloads-in-the-tfs-build-server). That has been answered, but now I've got a couple more questions.

First, I've got the Visual Studio Build Tools for VS 2019. At the time I downloaded it, I assumed that it would cover VS 2017 as well. I just want to make sure my assumption is correct. If it isn't, then I'd better go back and get the Visual Studio Build Tools for VS 2017

Second question, do I also need to get the [agents for VS 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019)? I know I'm going to expose the fact that I'm still pretty new at TFS, it can't be helped because I am still new at it. Anyway, I thought that the build agent already installed on the build server would be sufficient. That it would use whatever version of Visual Studio is available to it. If I'm wrong about that, I'd like to know, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It's should be contains the tools and compilers that include in Build Tools for VS 2017, but it can't be guaranteed that if project written in VS 2017 will be compiled prefect in VS 2019 (build tools), it should be ok but maybe in some cases not.

You can start using only Build Tools for VS 2019, if builds will start to fail try to install also Build Tools for VS 2017.

2) The "agents for VS 2019" are not TFS agents. for build projects you installed build tools and TFS agent and it's enough.

But, if you want to run Load/Functional/Automated Tests you need to install the "agents for VS 2019" because you have only the VS Build Tools and not the full VS (the full VS is coming with tests agents and more).